# Node.js Javascipt object overwritting instead of merging

Tags: node.js, for-loop, javascript-objects

I'm running a for...of loop. The config file I'm using, `config`, loops twice and what I want is to take those 2 configurations and add them both to a Javascript object. The issue I'm having is that when I go to merge the data from the first loop with the data from the second loop using the spread syntax, the data from the second loop is overwriting the whole object instead of merging. (I've taken out the irrelevant parts of the function below)

```
  Datasets() {
      var newObject = {};
      var config = ConfigFile;
      for (const [h_name, h_config] of Object.entries(config)) {
        var d = new datasetobj(h_name, this.configuration);       
        var mergedObj = { ...d, ...h_config }; // this works fine and merges the 2 objects together as expected

        console.log(newObject); // This shows an empty object the first loop (as expected), then it shows the correct data from the first loop in the second loop.

        newObject = { ...newObject, ...mergedObj }; // Here, instead of merging the objects, it is overwriting the entire object with mergedObj
        console.log(newObject);
      }
}
```

What I'm expecting to happen to `newObject` is:  { } -> {a} -> {ab}

What's actually happening though, is: { } -> {a} -> {b}

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in codesandbox / jsfiddle? 
looking at the code it doesn't look like there's something wrong, unless both newObject and mergedObj are empty.

Comment: Sure, here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/2topher/p3fk17v0/1/

Comment: The console output in jsfiddle looks a little weird since I'm not pulling in actual data, but you can still see the issue.

I can confirm that newObject is only empty when it is originally created before the loop and that mergedObj is also not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the 2 objects had the same keys. The objects were supposed to have a name then all of the keys like this:

```
objA:
  key1:v1
---
objB:
  key1:v2
```

*BUT* they both had all the keys at the top level like this:

```
key1:v1
---
key1:v2
```

If 2 objects have the same keys, the first one will be overwritten by the second one. I redid the way the objects were being created and everything worked out